# Using triggers to fire the Items.CurrentChanging event on a tab control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM for a project and my question relates to using triggers.

The Items property of the TabControl has a property called items and items has an event called CurrentChanging. (TabControl.Items.CurrentChanging)

How do I wire up an event on the child of my main object using triggers?

Thanks

Edit:
This is using WPF and the MVVM-Light toolkit

Comment: @BoltClock. Good Point ;) it's WPF. I have edited my question. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by creating a Routed Event that was raised when the CurrentChangingEvent was fired in the code behind.

To make it fire I needed to add in the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;